# How to skip row 2nd in excel before import datatable

Tags: excel, import, datatable

if (txtPath.Text.Substring(txtPath.Text.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
{
Con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"");
}
else
{
Con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"");
}

```
            Con.Open();
            //string query = String.Format("select *from [{0}$] where skipping A2:Z2", "Sheet1");
            //OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Con);
            OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT *   FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE LIMIT A2", Con);
            //OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT *   FROM [Sheet1$]", Con);
            myCommand.Fill(myDataSet);              
            string MaCT = myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName.ToUpper();
```

Comment: Hi Chi Pu Fan, welcome to SO. Please share more details and describe which what kind of error you are encountering.

Comment: I try to skip or delete 2nd row in excel before add to dataset.table .I don't know how to do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.